# Checking length of lists and printing name of longest and shortest lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Hey Ive got a project where I'm generating random numbers between 1 and 4 49 times and adding them to a list. These numbers are supposed to represent a color of a smartie. Then I had to seperate the results of that list into lists of their own, which I also managed to do. But now it wants me to compare those lists by length and print out the name of the longest and shortest list. (Which color has the most, and which color has the least.) Heres what Ive tried. Im not sure how to go about this really.

```
list = open('list.txt', 'w')
fields = None
redList = []
blueList = []
yellowList = []
greenList = []
biggestList = 0
smallestList = 0

for count in range(49):
    randNum = random.randint(1, 4)
    if randNum == 1:
        smartyColor = 'Red'
        list.write('1 ')

    elif randNum == 2:
        smartyColor = 'Blue'
        list.write('2 ')

    elif randNum == 3:
        smartyColor = 'Green'
        list.write('3 ')

    elif randNum == 4:
        smartyColor = 'Yellow'
        list.write('4 ')

list.close()

list = open('list.txt', 'r')
for line in list:
    fields = line.split()
for field in fields:
    if field == '1':
        redList.append(field)
    elif field == '2':
        blueList.append(field)
    elif field == '3':
        greenList.append(field)
    elif field == '4':
        yellowList.append(field)

if redList == blueList:
    print("There are as many red smarties as blue smarties.")
elif redList  == greenList:
    print("There are as many red smarties as green smarties.")
elif redList == yellowList:
    print("There are as may red smarties as yellow smarties.")

if blueList == greenList:
    print("There are as many blue smarties as there are green smarties.")
elif blueList == yellowList:
    print("There are as many blue smarties as yellow smarties.")

if greenList == yellowList:
    print("There are as many green smarties as there are yellow smarties.")

if redList > biggestList:
    biggestList = redList
elif blueList > biggestList:
    biggestList = blueList
elif greenList > biggestList:
    biggestList = greenList
else:
    biggestList = yellowList

print("The biggest list was ",biggestList,"." )

if redList < smallestList:
    smallestList = redList.Length
elif blueList < smallestList:
    smallestList = blueList
elif greenList < smallestList:
   smallestList = greenList
else:
   smallestList = yellowList

print("The smallest list was ",smallestList,"." )
```

Comment: Other modules such as Numpy and Pandas should not be used?

Comment: You are comparing the lists, you should compare the length!

Comment: @BrunoMello How do I specify the list length in the comparison?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  "I don't know how to do this" suggests that you need more exercises with the applicable data structures, or perhaps a local friend to help you work through problem analysis.  It is not a Stack Overflow issue.  Also see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); most of this code is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: You can use `len()`

Comment: @GilseungAhn It's for school so I'm assuming we wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use > with 2 lists, what you have to do is the following:

Where you have:

```
if list_a > list_b:
```

Replace by:

```
if len(list_a)>len(list_b):
```

Comment: Oh my gosh it was that simple XDD I tried using that before, but I didn't get the brackets. Ty sir!

Comment: Yeah It works. Now I just have to figure out how to print out the name of a list stored in a variable and not the entire list. Any ideas?

Comment: You can ask another question in the forum, so it is more organized

Answer (score 0):

Your question at its essence is:

> Given a bunch of lists, how I print out the smallest and biggest of
>   them (by size)?

Here you go:

```
def print_biggest_and_smallest(mylists):
    mylists.sort(key = lambda x:len(x))
    smallest = mylists[0]
    biggest = mylists[-1]
    print(smallest, biggest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
for i in range(49):
    l.append(random.randint(1,4))

colors = [[],[],[],[]]
for i in l:
        colors[int(i)-1].append(i)

length_colors= [len(i) for i in colors]
min, max = 0,0

for i in range(1,len(colors)):
    if length_colors[min] > length_colors[i]:
        min = i
    elif length_colors[max] < length_colors[i]:
        max = i

print(length_colors)
print("Biggest list = ", colors[max], ",with ", length_colors[max], " elements")
print("Smallest list = ", colors[min], "with ", length_colors[min], " elements")
```

It would help if you could use numpy, then you could just use np.argmax / np.argmin.